# Django admin's `add_form` doesn't shows `CustomUserCreationForm` in admin

Tags: python, django

I created the following `CustomUserCreationForm`:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'age']
```

I used this form on `SignUpView` and it works as expected, namely shows all fields we stated above, but when I use it in admin it only shows `username`, `password1` and `password2` fields.

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['email', 'username', 'age', 'is_staff', ]


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

when I add a user in admin page, it shows following fields and not all fields stated in `UserCreationForm`:
[image]

why is this happening and how do I solve it?

edit: added custom user model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

edit 2: `signupview` works fine except admin user creation form: 
[image]

Comment: have you added custom user in settings? AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app_name.CustomUser'

Comment: yes i did, `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'`

Comment: please post your custom user model

Comment: @bmons I did, please read the updated question

Comment: `SignupView` shows all fields stated in `CustomUserCreationForm` but admin panel doesn't show them.

Comment: you have to register your custom user in admin also

Comment: I already did:
`admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    ---------
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'age')}
        ),
    )


admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

Comment: thank you, can you please say why you unregistered Group? and I find it a  it hard to understand your comment? a bit further elaboration please.

Comment: since we're not using Django's built-in permissions ...https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: I just read it but couldn't understand it. what is `'classes': ('wide',)` and `get_fieldsets`?